# EPSON android SDK is not working with TM-T81 series

Tags: java, android, printing, thermal-printer, epson

I was download epson android sdk from 
https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5228&pcat=7&pid=4179.
I have an Epson TM-T81 series printer,When i try to connect this sdk with my printer it show Error code(ERR_UNSUPPORTED),but when i change the printer series to TM-T82 or some other from the spinner, it works fine with my TM-T81 printer but it is not working when i select TM-T81.What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. This answer Will Help you.

```
public boolean initializeObject(Printer printerSeries) {

    try {

       // mPrinter=new Printer(Printer.TM_T88,Printer.LANG_EN,mContext);
        or
         mPrinter=new Printer(printerSeries,Printer.LANG_EN,mContext);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ShowMsg.showException(e, "Printer", mContext);
        return false;
    }

    mPrinter.setReceiveEventListener(new com.epson.epos2.printer.ReceiveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPtrReceive(Printer printer, int i, PrinterStatusInfo printerStatusInfo, String s) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public synchronized void run() {
                    disconnectPrinter();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            disconnectPrinter();
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return true;
}

public void finalizeObject() {
    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return;
    }

    mPrinter.clearCommandBuffer();

    mPrinter.setReceiveEventListener(null);

    mPrinter = null;
}

public boolean printData(String receiptPrintIP) {
    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!connectPrinter(receiptPrintIP)) {
        return false;
    }

    PrinterStatusInfo status = mPrinter.getStatus();
    if (!isPrintable(status)) {
        ShowMsg.showMsg(printPOS2Help.makeErrorMessage(status), mContext);
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.sendData(Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ShowMsg.showException(e, "sendData", mContext);
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            // Do nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean connectPrinter(String receiptPrintIP) {
    boolean isBeginTransaction = false;
    if (mPrinter == null) {
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.connect(receiptPrintIP, Printer.PARAM_DEFAULT);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ShowMsg.showException(e, "connect", mContext);
        return false;
    }

    try {
        mPrinter.beginTransaction();
        isBeginTransaction = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ShowMsg.showException(e, "beginTransaction", mContext);
    }

    if (isBeginTransaction == false) {
        try {
            mPrinter.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Epos2Exception e) {
            // Do nothing
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```